# How to use devise_token_auth with Devise, Angular and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm trying to use Mongoid, devise, devise_token_auth and ng-token-auth for an token based authorisation for an API written in Rails with Mongoid and Angular as the client.

The problem is when I follow the steps to install `devise_token_auth` I get an error when I restart my Rails app: `undefined method`table_exists?' for User:Class`

I'm assuming that because I'm using Mongoid the `User` class don't have the `table_exists?` method.

How can I get around this? Or, more importantly how can I get this to work?

**EDIT: Here's my User class**

```
class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Enum

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  field :confirmed_at,         type: Time
  field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time
  field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  attr_accessor :reset_token

  enum :role, [:admin, :author]

  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
  before_create :set_auth_token

  field :first_name,                                        type: String
  field :last_name,                                         type: String
  field :domain,                                                type: String
  field :payment_details,                               type: Hash
  field :subscriber,                                        type: Boolean
  field :stripe_details,                                type: Hash
  field :theme,                                                 type: String

  # Validation
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token


  # Get rid of devise-token_auth issues from activerecord
  def table_exists?
    true
  end

  def columns_hash
    # Just fake it for devise-token-auth; since this model is schema-less, this method is not really useful otherwise
    {} # An empty hash, so tokens_has_json_column_type will return false, which is probably what you want for Monogoid/BSON
  end

  def set_default_role
      self.role ||= :admin
  end

end
```

**EDIT 2: Adding stack trace**

http://pastebin.com/yMcr9mZ4

Comment: include this in your gemfile
```
gem 'rails',                      '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'mongoid',                    '~> 6.2', '>= 6.2.1'
gem 'devise_token_auth',          git: 'https://github.com/BunHouth/devise_token_auth.git', branch: 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid-locker', '~> 0.3.4'
```
run `bundle install` and follow master branch configuration. it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing errors or source code, my guess is that your `User` class looks something like:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  # Maybe some devise options here
end
```

Methods like `table_exists?` and `columns_hash` are used by `devise-token-auth` because it's assumed that your user models inherit from `ActiveRecord`. See, for example, lines 87-94 of `devise_token_auth/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb`:

```
  module ClassMethods
    protected


    def tokens_has_json_column_type?
      table_exists? && self.columns_hash['tokens'] && self.columns_hash['tokens'].type.in?([:json, :jsonb])
    end
  end
```

One solution is to monkey patch your way to victory. And/or you can implement those missing methods on your `User` class:

```
class User
  # Get rid of devise-token_auth issues from activerecord
  def self.table_exists?
    true
  end

  def self.columns_hash
    # Just fake it for devise-token-auth; since this model is schema-less, this method is not really useful otherwise
    {} # An empty hash, so tokens_has_json_column_type will return false, which is probably what you want for Monogoid/BSON
  end

  def self.serialize(*args)

  end

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User


  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Enum

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Confirmable
  field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  field :confirmed_at,         type: Time
  field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time
  field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable



  attr_accessor :reset_token

  enum :role, [:admin, :author]

  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
  before_create :set_auth_token

  field :first_name,                                        type: String
  field :last_name,                                         type: String
  field :domain,                                                type: String
  field :payment_details,                               type: Hash
  field :subscriber,                                        type: Boolean
  field :stripe_details,                                type: Hash
  field :theme,                                                 type: String

  # Validation
  valid_email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token




  def set_default_role
      self.role ||= :admin
  end



end
```

Having used `devise-token-auth` without `ActiveRecord` myself, I can tell you it's possible. Rather than do routes with `mount_devise_token_auth_for`, I implemented my own controllers that used the same underlying functions. Look at the controllers in `devise-token-auth` and you'll see that you can follow the same flow, while replacing `ActiveRecord` methods with `Mongoid` methods. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! It seems there's light at the end of the tunnel :) I've added the method as you've explained and still get the error. I'm updating my answer with my `User` class

Comment: Any idea of what might be happening? Thanks again for your help

Comment: I updated my example based on yours. You'll need to create the methods before you include the devise_token_auth concern, so I re-ordered them. I don't know much about Mongoid, but assuming that it can serialize an array (`tokens` in this case), then overwriting the `serialize` method should be fine. Finally, your regex will cause errors for being a dynamic constant assignment, so I made it lowercase.

Comment: All 3 methods that we create here are used by `devise_token_auth` to figure out if it needs to serialize an array of tokens to JSON in a SQL database. You'll need to verify that the token de/serialization still works as expected for the gem.

Comment: I've accepted as answer but to be honest I gave all up am writing my own authentication and  angular library.

Answer (score 0):

include this in your gemfile

```
gem 'rails',                      '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'mongoid',                    '~> 6.2', '>= 6.2.1'
gem 'devise_token_auth',          git: 'https://github.com/BunHouth/devise_token_auth.git', branch: 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid-locker', '~> 0.3.4'
```

run `bundle install` and follow the `master` branch configuration. it works for me.